# How should I fur out cement board in shower stall to match the original mortar position?

Tags: shower, tile

I have a 1950's house where, in wet areas like shower stalls, the original mortar behind the tiles is 1 1/2'to 2' thick. I had to remove one side of a stall and need to replace it (it mighty be a little leaky otherwise :)).

Question is, to shim out the wall so the tile correctly meets in the corners and on the pan, should I just use a full sheet of 1/2'+ plywood behind the cement board, directly onto the studs, or just strips of plywood on the studs, or some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build out the framing with... more framing. Either sister studs at the correct projection depth, or cut furring strips. Fitting full sheets as filler is a waste of time and materials.